# VAR counts and toggles between selected elements but duplicates the attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on trivial seats reservation script. In my code I have a table imitating the seats. Every `td` element has "n" class assigned and contains unique ID(for example id='_21d'). The idea is to be able to click on up to 4 seats. At this point further selection should be forbidden, total number of seats counted and displayed as *"You selected X of 4 seats."* and the IDs of selected seats displayed in a string such as *"Your booked seats are: 14F, 11B, 4C, 10A"*.

I'm getting there, I managed to block the further selection after 4 seats are highlighted, the number of seats is counted properly and toggles +=1 & -=1 when clicking on the same seat repeatedly. Also the seats IDs are passed to the string **BUT** once clicked on the same seat again they are not removed. Instead, the IDs are duplicated and added to the string every time while toggling between the selected and unselected seat. Here is where I need a hand, how to make the ID toggling the same way as the seats counter does?

```
var seatsAlloc = 0;

$('#plan td.n').bind('click', function(event) {

if (!$(this).hasClass("taken"))
if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
seatsAlloc -= 1;
$(this).removeClass("selected");

} else if ($(".selected").length < 4) {
seatsAlloc += 1;
$(this).addClass("selected");

var chosen = ($(this).attr('id').substring(1));
var seatNumb = (chosen.toUpperCase() +" ");
}
$("#selSeats").append(seatNumb);
$('span#seatsAlloc').html(seatsAlloc);

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see you actually removing the seat name at any point, just adding it.  Regardless, instead of keeping track of the number of chosen seats I would just count them each time and rebuild the list at the same time.  Something like this -

```js
// I'm removing this because we can count the number of allocated 
// seats after each click easily enough
//var seatsAlloc = 0;
var maxSeatsAllowed = 4;
$('#plan td.n').bind('click', function(event) {
  if (!$(this).hasClass("taken"))
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
      $(this).removeClass("selected");
    } else if ($(".selected").length < maxSeatsAllowed) {
    $(this).addClass("selected");
  }
  // "map" will return a jQuery array of the id's 
  // of all the selected seats (with the first char 
  // removed) and "get" will then convert that array to a 
  // regular javascript array which can be "join"ed.  
  // We then replace the list with the new one.
  $("#selSeats").text($(".selected").map(function() {
    return this.id.substring(1);
  }).get().join(", "));
  // Count all the selected seats and replace the previous count
  $('span#seatsAlloc').text($(".selected").length + " seats of " + maxSeatsAllowed + " selected");
})
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="plan">
  <tr>
    <td class="n" id="_A1">A1</td>
    <td class="n" id="_A2">A2</td>
    <td class="n" id="_A3">A3</td>
    <td class="n" id="_A4">A4</td>
    <td class="n" id="_A5">A5</td>
    <td class="n" id="_A6">A6</td>
    <td class="n" id="_A7">A7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="n" id="_B1">B1</td>
    <td class="n" id="_B2">B2</td>
    <td class="n" id="_B3">B3</td>
    <td class="n" id="_B4">B4</td>
    <td class="n" id="_B5">B5</td>
    <td class="n" id="_B6">B6</td>
    <td class="n" id="_B7">B7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="n" id="_C1">C1</td>
    <td class="n" id="_C2">C2</td>
    <td class="n" id="_C3">C3</td>
    <td class="n" id="_C4">C4</td>
    <td class="n" id="_C5">C5</td>
    <td class="n" id="_C6">C6</td>
    <td class="n" id="_C7">C7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<span id="selSeats"></span>
<span id="seatsAlloc"></span>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Works like a charm, thank you.

Comment: Rebuilding the list is better than crazy string manipulation. The main point is to keep the data and it's representation separated, so you avoid this kind of problem all together. +1